# How can i get name box from excel?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm comparing 2 excel files cell by cell and when i found a difference i print it example DIFF Cell values at: Sch HI (1 of 4)!K40 => '6.0' v/s '5.0' cell position old value and new value

so instead of cell position i need to print the box name

```
 @Override
    public void reportDiffCell(CellPos c1, CellPos c2) {
        sheets.add(c1.getSheetName());
        rows.add(c1.getRow());
        cols.add(c1.getColumn());
        results.add("DIFF Cell values at: " + c1.getCellPosition() + " => '" + c1.getCellValue()
                + "' v/s '" + c2.getCellValue() + "'");
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NamedRanges) as a starting point. Bear in mind that one cell can be contained in multiple named ranges. So, you are probably better off iterating the named ranges independently of cell references - and then reporting on differences in those named ranges.

Answer (score 2):

An example of gathering the range names from a spreadsheet, so that they can be compared for a "diff" report...

For example, here is a spreadsheet with two named ranges:

```
Name     : animals
Refers to: Sheet1!$C$3:$D$4,Sheet1!$C$5

Name     : birds
Refers to: Sheet1!$B$8:$B$9
```

[image: named ranges]

The following code populates the range names and references into a map:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Name;

...

public Map<String, String> compare(String fileName) {

    Map<String, String> namesMap = new HashMap();

    File file = new File(fileName);
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(is);
        List<? extends Name> names = wb.getAllNames();

        names.forEach((name) -> {
            namesMap.put(name.getNameName(), name.getRefersToFormula());
        });

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // handler
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handler
    }

    return namesMap;
}
```

Now you can repeat this for each of your two Excel files, and then compare the keys and values in the two map objects (different range names; same names but different ranges of cells).

**UPDATE**: THe above sample was written using Open JDK 13. The following POI dependencies were used (assuming Maven):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> 
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId> 
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

Comment: hey which version of apache you are working with ?
i'm using    <version>3.9</version>

Comment: @JsNinja My example was written using POI 4.1.2 (and OpenJDK 13).  If you are using POI 3.9, then there are a couple of methods which I think are missing/different, for example `wb.getAllNames()` and `generateContiguous()` - and maybe also `WorkbookFactory`. The above code runs OK with POI 3.17. Is that is an option for you?

Comment: actually i changed to 4.1.2 i get several errors i tried 3.17 too kinda errors : 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.getPackageRelationship()Lorg/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/PackageRelationship;

Comment: @JsNinja - I updated the answer to show my POI dependencies, in case that helps.

Comment: i will be back to it if this doesn't work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649598/get-name-of-cell-apache-poi
look do you have an idea?

Comment: @JsNinja - I don't know - but it suggests the project's configuration is still pointing at an older library, somewhere (see [here](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/issues/208) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502210/how-to-fix-this-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apac)).

Answer (score 0):

You could add a VBA function to the workbook and call that from java...

```
Function CellName(r As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    CellName = r.Name.Name
    If Err Then CellName = r.Address(0, 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. Perhaps a workaround could be to place the above function in the workbook and then call it from java.